# Explain BNF syntax for NID in RFC 2141

Tags: regex, syntax, bnf, ebnf, urn

I am having trouble understanding some [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) syntax from [RFC2141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141).

The line is `<NID> ::= <let-num> [ 1,31<let-num-hyp> ]`.  I think it means that `<NID>` is a symbol for a string, with constrained by two rules:

1. The string must be begin with a single occurence of any of the `<let-num>` characters.
2. This character may be followed by 0-31 occurrences* of any of the `<let-num-hyp>` characters.

Am I reading this correctly?  Because, if I am, some of the implications are a bit confusing.

**equivalent to "optionally, 1-31 occurrences*

The complete BNF syntax for a `<NID>` (Namespace Identifier) in [RFC2141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141) is:

```
<NID>         ::= <let-num> [ 1,31<let-num-hyp> ]
<let-num-hyp> ::= <upper> | <lower> | <number> | "-"
<let-num>     ::= <upper> | <lower> | <number>
<upper>       ::= "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" |
                  "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" |
                  "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" |
                  "Y" | "Z"
<lower>       ::= "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" |
                  "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" |
                  "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" |
                  "y" | "z"
<number>      ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" |
                  "8" | "9"
```

Comment: That's how I read it.  What implications are confusing?  You didn't ask anything about that in your question.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham, @Don Roby - I was confused because further division of the "Namespace` is located in the `<NSS>` (Namespace Specific String), instead of in the `NID` (Namespace Identifier).  For example, in `urn:my-namespace:my-sub-namespace:my-resource-name`, the scheme is `urn`, the `NID` is `my-namespace`, and the `NSS` is `my-sub-namespace:my-resource-name`.  I had had incorrectly assumed that the `my-namespace:my-sub-namespace` would be the contents of the `NID`, but I realized my error after re-reading the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've interpreted it correctly.  What are the confusing implications?

```
<NID> ::= <let-num> [ 1,31<let-num-hyp> ]
```

means one occurrence of `<let-num>` followed optionally by up to 31 occurrences of `<let-num-hyp>`.

Taking into account the other definitions, this means a string of at least one character and at most 32 characters, consisting of letters of either case, numerals, and hyphens, with the first character not allowed to be a hyphen.